# How to remove Subscribe to Post (Atom) from blogger?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

Can anyone tell me better option to remove Subscribe to Post (Atom) from blogger than hiding the link by making it the same color as background?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to remove, maybe someday you can use it again. Perhaps simply by not showing, you can use the CSS `display: none`

```
.post-feeds, .blog-feeds {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. To find CSS in Blogger: edit Theme > Customize > Advanced >  in submenu SCROLL DOWN to 'Add CSS', and insert the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Find in template these blocks of code:

```
<b:includable id='feedLinks'>...Code here..</b:includable>
<b:includable id='feedLinksBody' var='links'>...Code here...</b:includable>
```

And replace them with this:

```
<b:includable id='feedLinks'/>
<b:includable id='feedLinksBody' var='links'/>
```